# MediaPlayer prepare faile: status=0x1

Tags: android, file

I have been working on fetching a list of music files from sdcard and I am successful in that but the problem is that when I click on a file it should play that file, but it is giving me this error.
Here's my code:

```
    private String[] mMusicList;
static long playlistid=0;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

  ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.phonemusiclist);

  mMusicList = getMusic();

  ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mMusicList);
  mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
  mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
    long arg3) {
      try {

        playSong(mMusicList[arg2]);
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }


  });


}

private String[] getMusic() {
  final Cursor mCursor = managedQuery(
  MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
  new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null,
  "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ") ASC");

  int count = mCursor.getCount();

  String[] songs = new String[count];
  int i = 0;
  if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
      songs[i] = mCursor.getString(0);
      i++;
    } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
  }

  mCursor.close();

  return songs;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void playSong(String path) throws IllegalArgumentException,IllegalStateException, IOException {
  String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
  .toString();

  path = extStorageDirectory + File.separator + path;

  mMediaPlayer.reset();
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
  mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
  mMediaPlayer.prepare();
  mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all remove `mCursor.close()`. Here you are closing the cursor which is a problem most of the time.

Secondly the evident mistake is the path you are specifying in `mediaplayer`. You are giving a path with a `separator`.

```
path = extStorageDirectory + File.separator + path;
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
```

which is wrong and file will not be found.

Instead change the code to

```
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(extStorageDirectory);
```

Hope you got it.
Cheer.:)

Comment: hello.. i already tried wt u suggested. but still the result is not achieved, seems i am going wrong somewhere else...

Comment: Then do **Edit** your question as people are misguided !